# Are Facebook's Test Apps Gone?

Tags: facebook, testing, cross-domain

Facebook's documentation for developers includes a [guide to test apps](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-apps). It's the perfect solution to hosting localhost:8000 domain for development and a live site simultaneously.

The dashboard link is the gone; even copying the link shown in Facebook's tutorial images is dead. How do I access Facebook's test apps?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like they moved this without updating their docs...
It's in your dashboard's "homepage" where you chose between your apps.
You have to click on the "more- triangle" in the top-right corner of your app-card and you will find the options "delete app" and "CREATE TEST APP" :)

https://developers.facebook.com/apps/